# Transactional Replication Errors - Missing and Duplicate Data at Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication, errors

We recently experienced errors with SQL Server Transactional Replication on a client's system. Replication is running from a SQL 2017 server to an Azure DB.

Initially some replicated update commands failed as the rows to be updated didn't exist on the subscriber database. We added the rows in manually to save reinitialising.

Following that some replicated insert commands failed as the rows to be inserted were already present on the subscriber. We deleted the rows and replication carried on as normal.

The client insists that they have changed no data on the subscriber database, and is asking how this happened.

Our best guess is that an error in the replication process caused commands to be sent more than once to the subscriber, but we are unsure why or how that would come about.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, or does anyone know how this may happen?

Comment: How would "an error in the replication process caused commands to be sent more than once" explain missing rows? Clearly an application or a user connecting to the subscriber, possibly by mistake,  and changing data there would be a more realistic explanation.

Comment: What isolation level is the Publisher using? (And thus the isolation level used by the snapshot agent...) How busy is the Publisher database with regard to write activity?

Comment: **Question:** "*does anyone know how this may happen?*" **Answer:** "*We added the rows in manually to save reinitialising.

Following that some replicated insert commands failed as the rows to be inserted were already present on the subscriber.*" - I've run into this very issue. Your best bet is to drop the table article from replication, drop the table at the Subscriber, re-add the table article to the Publication, re-initialize the Publication with a new snapshot.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, very true! I was more thinking about the rows that were already present on the subscriber causing the inserts to fail. I agree that the update failures are far more likely to be due to a mistaken delete on the subscriber. The client insists this didn't happen, so taking them at face vaue I am exploring other possible causes.

Comment: @AMtwo The publisher Isolation Level is Read committed, and it is a high traffic system that is very busy with write activity. Something else that I should probably have mentioned is that replication is going from an on premise SQL 2017 server to an Azure DB.

Comment: @J.D. Thanks, I understand, and that would definitely be the best option to be sure everything is correct. The client is looking to avoid this as they have a very busy 24/7 system and it would mean scheduling down time for their operation. Generating the snapshots causes blocking and deadlocks they want to avoid. We only added in two rows that were missing so that updates could complete, but there were multiple rows already existing on the subscriber in other tables causing inserts to fail. I doubt the client added these manually, so they must have got there by some other means.

Comment: @Lectric Unfortunately Replication and 24/7 uptime don't go hand-in-hand. If they want to minimize downtime with Replication, they need to architect their system better. E.g. considering RCSI to eliminate deadlocks / blocking issues, and using Views on top of the tables being replicated, as the database objects their applications reference. That way if they ever need to re-initialize the Publication, they can just update their views to re-point them to a static copy of the tables up until the Publication is re-initialized (or can restore a backup copy of the DB and re-point the views there).

Comment: I think unfortunately you guys have to bite the bullet and re-initialize the Publication. You should never manually modify the tables on the Subscriber side. Only DML changes are acceptable in Peer-to-Peer Replication or Bi-directional Transactional Replication topologies, if I recall correctly.